# Thread 1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeeb1aeff8)

Tags: swift, viper-architecture

I am trying to learn VIPER. I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/cr8resume/viper-architecture-for-ios-project-with-simple-demo-example-7a07321dbd29). I have these `Interactor` and `Presenter`:

```
class PPresenter: ViewToPresenterProtocol {
    
    var view: PresenterToViewProtocol?  
    
    var router: PresenterToRouterProtocol? = PRouter()
    
    var interactor: PresenterToInteractorProtocol? = PInteractor()

    
    func initiateFetch() {
        interactor?.fetchMatches()
    }
    
    func showMatchScreen(navigationC: UIViewController) {
        router?.pushToMatchDetailScreen(navigationC: navigationC)
    }
}

extension PPresenter: InteractorToPresenterProtocol {
    func matchFetched(match: MatchDetails?, banner: Banner?) {
        print(match!)
        
        print(banner!)
    }
    
    func matchFetchError() {
        //TODO
    }
}


class PInteractor: PresenterToInteractorProtocol {
    
    var presenter: InteractorToPresenterProtocol? = PPresenter()
    
    var live: Live?
    
    var upcoming: Upcoming?
    
    var banners: Banner?
    
    func fetchMatches() {
        let parameters = ["api_token" : Constants.USER_INFO["api_token"].rawValue,"player_id" : Constants.USER_INFO["player_id"].rawValue]
        
        ServiceHelper.sharedInstance.sendRequest(path: "get-predictor", params: parameters, showSpinner: true) { (response, error) in
            
            if let error = error {
                print("Unable to fetch match listing",error.localizedDescription)
                
                return
            } else {
                guard let obj = try? JSONDecoder().decode(MatchDetails.self, from: response.rawData()) else { self.presenter?.matchFetchError(); return }
                
                guard let bannerObj = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Banner.self,from: response.rawData()) else {self.presenter?.matchFetchError(); return }
                
                self.presenter?.matchFetched(match: obj, banner: bannerObj)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, what is happening here, I get the router working, the view is coming, it is calling presenter, the presenter is calling the interactor, the interactor is successfully calling the API and getting the data and now it is time to return the data received from `Interactor` to `Presenter` and here it constantly throwing the following error:

> Thread 1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeeb1aeff8)

Comment: Which line of code is throwing that error?

Comment: `presenter` in PInteractor class

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a cyclic call, maybe your interactor is not fully initialized and then you want data from it and then you got "Bad access error".

Comment: did you understand what I said? I mean you have two things, for example "A" and "B", you try to calculate "A" and cus of that you use "B", but cus of a mistake, when calculating "B", you refer to "A's value", you see cycle here? try to find such a pattern and solve it. in digest I mean "A" is depend on "B" and "B" is depend on "A" and that bad access error is often cus of this mistake.